# Registering Linux VM in environment from pipeline fails in config.sh

Tags: linux, azure, yaml, pipeline

I am creating a Linux VM from an Azure pipeline with az vm create and want to register it in my Azure environment afterwards with a Custom Script extension (az vm extension) like described [here](https://ronaldbosma.github.io/blog/2021/03/16/provision-an-azure-vm-in-an-azure-pipelines-environment/).

The config.sh command always fails and gives the following error response. Anyone an idea how to fix this?

./config.sh --environment --environmentname "myEnvironment" --acceptteeeula --agent $HOSTNAME --url myUrl --work _work --projectname 'routing' --auth PAT --token myToken --unattended

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3iRW.png)

Comment: Your script cannot access svc.sh . Either, it doesn't have permission on it or its path is wrong.

Comment: The svc.sh is not created yet as the config.sh fails before.